# Setting Three JS Orbit Controls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, three.js, javascript-objects

I am rendering a 3D wireframe model of a building with threeJS. But I'm having troubles with OrbitControls, because of my camera position.

I need to change the control as follows:

1. Pan will be controlled by the middle mouse button
2. Zoom will be controlled by the mouse wheel
3. Rotating will be controlled by the key Ctrl + middle mouse button

This is my main component:

```
class Render3D extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { elements, nodes } = this.props;

    // Set up the scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Set up the camera
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      10000
    );

    // Set camera position to an isometric view
    camera.position.set(-100, -100, 100);
    camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    camera.up.set(1, 1, 0);

    // Set up the renderer and mount the canvas to the DOM
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight * 0.8);
    this.mount.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create OrbitControls instance
    const controlsWrapper = new OrbitControlsWrapper(
      camera,
      renderer.domElement
    );
    const controls = controlsWrapper.controls;

    // Basic material for the lines
    const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: "#606470" });

    // For each element from the model
    elements.forEach((element) => {
      // New array that will be storing the points coordinates
      const points = [];
      // Start and end node's coordinates of the element
      const start = nodes[element.node_f];
      const end = nodes[element.node_i];

      // Updating points array
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(start.x, start.y, start.z));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(end.x, end.y, end.z));

      // Generating new geometry object from points
      const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
      // New 3D line object from geometry and material
      const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
      // Adding the line to the viewport
      scene.add(line);
    });

    // Animate the scene with requestAnimationFrame
    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();

  }

  // Render the scene. It is created a new container
  render() {
    return <div ref={(ref) => (this.mount = ref)} />;
  }
}
```

As you can see, OrbitControls is another component where will be found all the functionality described before

Thanks a lot!

I'm aware that there are several controls in threeJS (OrbitControls, TrackBallControls, ArcBallControls, etc). I have already tried with all of them, but because of the position of the camera I have not been able to make them work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set pan to the middle mouse button with [controls.mouseButtons](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=orbit#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.mouseButtons) and set `.enablePan = false`.

Then check for the CTRL key press [with the “keydown” event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) to enable pan. On “keyup” event you can disable pan again.